# Development questions related to Liferay 6

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay version 6.06. I have developed a Login Portlet using Liferay plugins SDK under which the View JSP consists of a login screen. Upon submitting credentials from this view JSP it will be received by the processAction Method of my Custom Portlet class. All this works good.

I have two questions:

1. Currently the Login Portlet is being part of Sample Category under Liferay screen (I want to have my own screen, where initially upon entering `http://localhost:8080/mycontext`, I want to show that Login screen).
2. And once the credentials are received inside the processAction method of my Custom Portlet class, I want to display my own two portlets.

Could anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Just a question: why does the default login portlet from liferay not serve to you? Why have you to write your own?

Comment: Hi Brandizzi , how the default login portlet will verify the credentials from my Database ?? for now this is not required , the main thing i want is from the custom screen submit how can i display my other two Portlets .

Comment: So all you want is to present a page with a login form and them a page with two already existing portlets? You do not need to write code for that! Just post a question about "how to present a page with a login form and them a page with two already existing portlets" and a lot of answers would be posted. For now, your questions are almost unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Beside you don't need a customized login for your Usecase, in case you still need to customize the login process you should:

build a hook which is a kind of plugin able to interact with Liferay's core functionalities.
In case you don't know take a look [here] http://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/hooks

or just use the property login.events.post=my.custom.PortletAction

and put your business logic after successfull user login